# crm cascade delete does not fire plugin

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dataverse

In crm i have solution with several entities. There are three that are causing a problem. Lets call them A, B and C.

A and B have a one to many relation with a cascading effect on deletion

B and C have a one to many relation *without* a cascading delete.

for B i have developed a crm plugin that, when deleted, it removes C as well. A sort of cascading delete plugin. I cannot create a cascading between B and C, since C is already in a cascading relationship with another entity.

When i delete any entity B, it fires off plugin code and deletes all children of C. When i delete any entity A, it cascade deletes B, but it does not fire off the plugin.

How can i ensure that the plugin does fire, without creating a plugin for entity A? I am fairly new at crm so i don't really know where to look for this kind of problem.

**UPDATE**

The plugin used to fire at the 'Pre-validation' stage. Changing it to 'Pre-operation' actually caused the plugin to fire. Unfortunately at this stage all Child references of the object where already removed. So now when A is deleted B is cascade deleted, and the plugin fires, but i cannot find any of it's child entity C references

Answer (score 1):

During cascade delete, only the triggering entity's `PreValidation` will be called.
For your entity `B` this means that this stage will be skipped.

As Joseph noted, setting a shared variable in `PreValidation` can generally be used to have information about already deleted data available in `PreOperation`, but you would have to ensure that this shared variable is set also when deleting `A`.

In case any of your entities are solution aware, deleting the solution with these records will also trigger a cascade delete, whereby `PreValidation` is only called on the `solution` entity.

Henk's suggestion is feasible, if the set of `C` records related to `B` do  not need any kind of processing, like sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object which will store the child references and pass it into the "Shared Variables" in the Pre-Validation stage.  Then you can access the shared variables in the pre-operation stage: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328579.aspx.  You will need plugins registered at both steps, but this will handle both of your challenges.